# Open Source advanced UITableView projects on GitHub?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm looking for some open source GitHub projects (or even blog posts), that show how some of the more complicated UITableView controllers are built on iOS that you can see happening in applications such as Tweetbot and Twitter (the old Tweetie).

I'm more or less interested in how to build views, context menus, etc, when an individual cell is clicked. There are some interesting drop downs and subviews that come into place very smoothly, almost as if they're a natural part of the iOS SDK.

Is there anything even remotely close available out there to learn from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out these sample projects:

---

[**CGRetractableSectionController**](https://github.com/gcamp/GCRetractableSectionController)

[image: Section]

---

[**UITableView Combo Box**](https://github.com/floriankrueger/iOS-Examples--UITableView-Combo-Box)

[image: Combo]

---

[**TISwipeableTableView**](https://github.com/thermogl/TISwipeableTableView)

[image: Swipeable]

---

(Thanks to http://cocoacontrols.com/ for the screenshots)

Comment: This is great, does anybody know if these can be combined -- swipeable retractable table view?

Answer (score 1):

[SSToolkit](https://github.com/samsoffes/sstoolkit/) has SSCollectionView which uses a UITableView to create a collection view.

Answer (score 0):

very interesting: http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/12/uitableview-construction-drawing-and.html